# Putting markup extension into resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, catel

In my WPF application I use value converters from Catel framework. For convenience they derive from `MarkupExtension`and return themselves from `ProvideValue` so I can just write `{Binding Converter={catel:BooleanToCollapsingVisibilityConverter}}` instead of adding them to a resource dictionary.

In some cases I have very long converter properties, so it is more convenient to put them into a resource dictionary like `<UserControl.Resources><catel:BooleanToCollapsingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyConverter" Link="..."/></UserControl.Resources>` and reference them as a `StaticResource`. But when I do so, the project fails to compile with the following error: *The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context*.

Is there a way to store such objects in resource dictionaries?

As a workaround I can inherit from desired value converter and put initialization code into a constructor, but this is not as convenient.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a case of "wrong type in xaml and code-behind"? Normally this is because the namespace or class in the code-behind is changed but the one in xaml is not.

Comment: @geert-van-horrik I checked this case first, the class name is valid. The projects begins to compile when I remove the converter from the resource dictionary.

Comment: Can you upload a repro here: http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/

Comment: I always encounter the same problem. Then answer is to put the resource in app.xaml instead. It's arguably more useful there anyway.